# When I pass State from parent to Child, it is passing as undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So, I'm trying to build a Modal in react and when I pass A state using useState to the child, it is being passed as undefined. I want it to show only if it's true. When I console log from parent it shows false as I have set it but in the child it says undefined and nothing happens. I was planning on changing the state to true on click.

Parent --

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Modal from './Modal'

function AddNewTodo() {
    const [ShowModal,setShowModal] = useState(false)
    console.log(ShowModal);
  return (
    <div className='AddNewTodo'>
        <div className='btn'>
       
        <button onClick={()=>setShowModal(true)} >
            + New Todo
        </button>
       

        </div>

        <Modal show={ShowModal} setShowModal ={setShowModal} >
            <div>
                Hello-25658
               
            </div>
        </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AddNewTodo
```

Child --

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'

function Modal({ children, Show, setShowModal }) {
    const modalRef = useRef()
    
    console.log(Show);

    const closeModal = (e) => {
        if (e.taget === modalRef.current) {
            setShowModal(false)
        }
    }
    

        return (
            Show &&
            <div>Hi</div>
            // <>
            // <div className='Modal' ref={modalRef} onClick={closeModal}>
            //     <div className='container'>
            //         {children}
            //     </div>
            // </div>
            // </>
        )
}

export default Modal
```

Comment: You're passing a `show={showModal}` prop to your Modal component, Modal doesn't have a `show` prop. Try changing `Show` to `show`.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent is passing `show` when your child props are trying to get `Show`:

This:

```
function Modal({ children, Show, setShowModal})
```

should be:

```
function Modal({ children, show, setShowModal})
```

Also should look at prettier because you have a lot of space issues and it will help in your code writing. Good practice to has your useState as:

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)
```